# Vectorizing a loop with a "continue" branch in it

Tags: c++, optimization, parallel-processing, vectorization, openmp

I am currently undergoing a course in which we were given access to a supercomputer. The CPU is an Intel(R) Xeon(R) Gold 6240 CPU. Our task was to vectorize (but we were not allowed to use parallelization) the calculation of mandelbrot set. The goal is to make the code as fast as possible. I tried a number of optimizations. Calculating only the top half of the mandelbrot set then copying the values down, utilizing all possible OpenMP pragmas, and trying to vectorize every loop. My code, however, is way slower than what it is supposed to be (~900ms, while the reference solution is on ~500ms). I need help making this code run much faster. We compile on the `icc` compiler with these flags `-O3 -mavx2 -xHost -g -qopenmp-simd -qopt-report=1 -qopt-report-phase=vec`. I ran an Advixe Profiler, and received the following times on the inner loop. However, over multiple runs of the profiler, the times spent on each line varied significantly, though most time was always spent on the `pointsRemaining` and `i2` or `r2` variables:

[image]

This is my code (it will be run from a custom script - I cannot change the compilation, nor can I change pretty much anything like width or height of the set - but those two will be multiples of 4096, co all aligning is okay). For every line in the image, it computes the iterations (whose number is given by the script that runs the calculator, usually ~100-500). As long as at least one point did not diverge out of the mandelbrot set, the program calculates the iterations for all the points in a line (I tried skipping calculating for every point, but adding the "if" clause that is commented out only slowed down the code - iI think if I manage to vectorize the commented "if", it would run much faster):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstring>
#include <stdlib.h>


#include "LineMandelCalculator.h"


LineMandelCalculator::LineMandelCalculator(unsigned matrixBaseSize, unsigned limit) :
    BaseMandelCalculator(matrixBaseSize, limit, "LineMandelCalculator")
{
    data = (int *)(_mm_malloc(height * width * sizeof(int), 64));
    zReal = (float *)(_mm_malloc(width * sizeof(float), 64));
    zImag = (float *)(_mm_malloc(width * sizeof(float), 64));
    iteration = (int *)(_mm_malloc(width * sizeof(int), 64));
    calculated_reals = (float *)(_mm_malloc(width * sizeof(float), 64));


    for (int i = 0; i < width; ++i) {
        calculated_reals[i] = x_start + i * dx;
        zReal[i] = 0.0f;
        zImag[i] = 0.0f;
        iteration[i] = limit;
    }
}

LineMandelCalculator::~LineMandelCalculator() {
    _mm_free(data);
    _mm_free(zReal);
    _mm_free(zImag);
    _mm_free(iteration);
    _mm_free(calculated_reals);

    data = NULL;
    zReal = NULL;
    zImag = NULL;
    iteration = NULL;
    calculated_reals = NULL;
}

int * LineMandelCalculator::calculateMandelbrot() {
    int *pdata = data;
    int half_height = height / 2;
    float *zReal = this -> zReal;
    float *zImag = this -> zImag;
    float *calculated_reals = this -> calculated_reals;
    int * iteration = this -> iteration;
    int limit = this -> limit;
    int width = this -> width;
    float dx = (float)this -> dx;
    float dy = (float)this -> dy;

    for (int i = 0; i < half_height; i++) {
        float y = y_start + i * dy;

        #pragma omp simd simdlen(64) aligned(zReal, zImag, iteration:64)
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++) {
            zReal[j] = calculated_reals[j];
            zImag[j] = y;
            iteration[j] = limit;
        }

        int pointsRemaining = width; 

        for (int k = 0; k < limit && pointsRemaining!=0; ++k) {
            pointsRemaining = 0; 

            #pragma omp simd simdlen(64) reduction(+:pointsRemaining) aligned(zReal, zImag, calculated_reals, iteration:64)
            for (int j = 0; j < width; j++) {
                //if(iteration[j]!=limit){
                //    continue;
                //}
                float r2 = zReal[j] * zReal[j];
                float i2 = zImag[j] * zImag[j];
                bool inside = (r2 + i2 <= 4.0f);

                if (inside)pointsRemaining ++;

                zImag[j] = 2.0f * zReal[j] * zImag[j] + y;
                zReal[j] = r2 - i2 + calculated_reals[j];

                if (!inside && iteration[j] == limit){
                    iteration[j] = k;
                }
            }
        }

        memcpy(pdata + i * width, iteration, width * sizeof(int));

        memcpy(pdata + (height - i - 1) * width, pdata + i * width, width * sizeof(int));
    }

    return data;
}
```

Comment: I imagine that one trick could be to use tiling to split the `j` loop into an outer and an inner loop where the tile size is the vector size s.t. the inner loop gets vectorized, but you can use the `continue` in the outer loop.

Comment: @paleonix Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, we are not allowed to use cache blocking (tiling).

Comment: Have you tried `pointsRemaining += (inside ? 1 : 0)`?

Comment: @paleonix I have, sadly, it led to no increase in speed.

Comment: I think it will be hard to find any answer without knowing the CPU architecture and the exact compiler/-options/OpenMP implementation to allow e.g. looking at the assembly on Compiler Explorer.

Comment: I think that my first proposal would only fit the term "cache blocking" if you would also swap the outer `j` loop with the `k` loop. Are you sure that just splitting the `j` loop with no influence on the order of memory loads/stores is not allowed?

Comment: The provided code does not build since some variables are missing and it is not even complete so we cannot test it. Reproducible are important to help you.

Answer (score 3):

This is not a complete answer, because it is not completely clear for me, what you are "allowed" to do (e.g., are you allowed to write this manually with intrinsics?) -- and I don't have much experience fudging with OpenMP. But there is a lot that can be optimized with your code.

First of all, the `pointsRemaining!=0` condition is essentially useless (it is always true, unless you compute a line which is entirely outside the Mandelbrot set, i.e., if `abs(y) > 1.12...`).

Checking the condition would make sense however, if you compute smaller tiles.
For example, if you compute, 1x16 or 4x4 tiles, which would fit into a register. Then 16 `bool inside` variables can be merged to a `__mmask16 inside_mask`, and `pointsRemaining!=0` would be equivalent to `inside_mask!=0` (which can be checked with a single `ktest`).

(This essentially answers your `continue`-Question, only that you would `break` out of the `for(k)`-loop instead).

Furthermore,

```
for(k=0; k<limit; ++k) {
   // ...
   if (!inside && iteration[j] == limit){
      iteration[j] = k;
   }
}
```

is equivalent to starting with `iteration[j]=0`, and doing

```
for(k=0; k<limit; ++k) {
   // ...
   if(inside) ++iteration[j]
}
```

Assuming you have 16 `iteration[]` values in a register, this can be done by a single `_mm512_mask_add_epi32` (since you have the mask anyway).

Overall, you don't need any `zReal`, `zImag`, `iteration` temporary arrays at all, because all computations can be done entirely in registers (you likely need to calculate with 2 or 4 sets of registers at the same time, to avoid latency-induced bottlenecks). Even the benefit of precomputing `calculated_reals` is dubious, since the next set of 16 values can be calculated from the previous with a simple `vaddps`.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is certainly due to `!inside && iteration[j] == limit` which needs to be **lazily evaluated** in C and C++. Compilers fail to vectorize such a condition because fetching `iteration[j]` has a visible behavior : the compiler cannot evaluate `iteration[j]` because `j` might be outside the bounds of `iteration` based on the value of `!inside`. As a result, ICC (and other compilers) cannot vectorize the entire loop and generate a *slow cascade of conditional jumps*.

If you know such a condition can be eagerly evaluated, then you can replace it with `(!inside) & (iteration[j] == limit)`. Expressions using the binary `&` operator are not lazily evaluated. This enable ICC to generate a [fully vectorized code](https://godbolt.org/z/d889crqvs).

That being said, the generated **code is huge** (about 12 KiB) with 1.5 KiB for the hot loop. A too big code can be detrimental for performance. Indeed, modern x86-64 processors translate instructions to micro-instruction (uops). The translation can often be a bottleneck for hot loops like this. Thus, they have a uops cache not to retranslate instruction but it has a limited size. A too big loop causes the uops cache to miss and instruction to be re-decoded over and over which is slow. Regarding the exact target CPU used, it might be an issue or not. On a Intel(R) Xeon(R) Gold 6240 which is a Cascade Lake CPU, I do not expect to be a significant bottleneck. Note that the alignment of the instructions also matter, especially on Cascade Lake (see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61016915/12939557)). At first glance, `simdlen(64)` is why the generated code is so big. It may not be reasonable. At least, certainly not for AVX-2 where `simdlen(32)` should certainly be preferred.

You specify **conflicting compilers flags**. Indeed, [`-xHost`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71489412/what-exactly-is-the-xhost-flag) tells the compiler to use the available instructions set of the target machine (AFAIK AVX-512 on your target platform) while `-mavx2` tells the compiler it can use AVX-2. `-mavx2` is thus useless with `-xHost`. Specify whether you want to use AVX-2 or AVX-512 to the compiler, not both. Your target CPU appear to support 2 AVX-512 units so AVX-512 is the best solution here.

Once vectorized, the code is not bad, but not very efficient either. A very good Mandelbrot implementation should spend most of its time doing **FMA instructions**. This does not seem the case here. However, it looks like the AVX-512 ALUs are the bottleneck which is quite good. Doing less conditions is certainly something you should try.

---

The rule of thumb is to look the assembly code generated by your compiler when you are optimizing a code. This is critical. Profiling using low-level tools is also very important. Without that, you are blind and optimization can become very difficult. It can be good to reduce unrolling (`simdlen(64)` here) in order to get a smaller assembly code that is easier to evaluate (humans can hardly evaluate the quality of assembly codes having thousands of instructions though there are tools can help a lot).

---

### Notes

There are methods to detect points that will never converge. They can be useful to break the iteration loop early when the number of iterations is big.

Iterating over a whole line can make the computation sub optimal if the line does not fit in the L1 cache.

SIMD registers can be used inefficiently if >50% of the items already converged. Reordering items can improve performance a bit when the number of iteration is huge. This is pretty hard to do efficiently in C++ using OpenMP though.

Comment: Thank you for your thorough answer. I am unfortunately unable to provide a reproducible example, as the rest of the source files is hidden from us (apart from the header and the file I provided). I managed to speed up by 200% by cache blocking - I split the for loops into smaller ones that fit inside L1 cache (this, however, is prohibited in this assignment).  I managed to speed up the code with your help, but I think I should try to find a more efficient implementation of the calculation, as it is VERY inefficient, as you have remarked. Thank you again for the help, your notes helped me!